# Devise Registration#update via JS in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to update the User model through Devise with AJAX and have Devise respond with the proper javascript file.

I want to submit the form remotely to the registrations#update action, but this isn't working with the default response from Devise, which uses the following from the RegistrationsController:

```
respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
```

The above tries to redirect to the default route instead of rendering the update.js.erb file. I am able to overwrite the action and have it work with the following change:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
 end
```

But, this seems very brute force as I'm overriding the entire action. Is there a simple way for Devise to know to respond with javascript instead of doing its default redirect?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://natashatherobot.com/devise-rails-sign-in/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply had to add a line to the RegistrationsController so that Devise knows to respond_to both html and js.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :html, :js
end
```

Reading up on how respond_with really helped. Couple of good links:

[Rails API Responder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html)

[AsciiCast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3)

Comment: Interestingly, this solution works for me when the #create action takes the sad path and puts errors on the resource, in which case `create.js.erb` is called like you would expect. This is with `remote: true` in the form.  But in the happy case it responds with HTML.  I saw a similar problem with sessions#destroy, where I had to override a private Devise method (`respond_to_on_destroy`) to get it to respond with format.js.  So at least in some cases, Devise has pushed their response code down into controller methods where you can't get at it without overiding private methods.

Answer (score 3):

I recently soved this by making the following adjustments, in addition to adding `remote: true` to the form:

**config/initializers/devise**:

```
# If http headers should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

**config/routes.rb**:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

**controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb**:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  respond_to :html, :js

end
```

**views/users/registrations/create.js.erb**:

```
alert('success');
```

**views/users/registrations/new.js.erb**:

```
alert('invalid');
```

Comment: It's misleading that `http_authenticatable_on_xhr` should be set to `false` for this to work.

Comment: @JPSilvashy perhaps Rails or Devise has changed a little in the last three years, and `http_authenticatable_on_xhr` is no longer required, like it was at the time of the answer. I don't really use devise much anymore... Did it work with just the other steps, and without adjusting `http_authenticatable_on_xhr`? If so I will update this answer (or feel free to submit your own).