# How to login and signup using ajax under devise gem rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I want to login and sign up user using devise library and using ajax.

Here is my complete code that seems not working. The problem is both ajax calls run at once on the modal.

I am unable to do this with ajax means my page redirects to users/sign_in if I types in wrong password when it shouldn't and show me error message on run time based on ajax response. both ajax functions do not working.

I have followed [this](http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/) blog to integrate it:

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-Transaction': 'SignUp Post',
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: "/users",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "user": {"email": "email", "password": "password", "password_confirmation": "password"}
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log("Success1");
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log("Errors2");
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-Transaction': 'SignIn Post',
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: "/users/sign_in",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "user": {"email": "email", "password": "password", "remember_me": 1}
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log("Success3");
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log("Errors4");
        }
    });
});
```

Registration Controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  clear_respond_to 
  respond_to :json
end
```

Sessions Controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController  
  respond_to :json
end
```

Routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations'}
```

Comment: Maybe you can clarify - __not working for me actually.__?

Comment: I have updated. @Зелёный

Comment: Have you tried to customize a `create` action in your controllers?

Comment: Yes I have tried and posted my code as well.

Comment: i can't see anything, your controller just inherit from `devise` controllers.

Comment: Basically, I have just followed the blog and made the same changes in my controllers and project and found it is not working as expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Devise Registration#update via JS in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348724/devise-registrationupdate-via-js-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is both ajax calls run at once on the modal.

Well, the simplest solution to make them run one after another is to make the first one synchronous:

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,

  // all your other stuff goes here
  // ...

})
```